# Using DNS name as host in database.yml does not work with rails application

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a setup where I would like to connect to the database using DNS name instaed of ipaddress and that seems to be not working.
If I chnage the host from DNS to ipaddress used for the DNS it works.

I get following error

```
015-01-17T22:03:22.79643Z 10413 FATAL: \nMysql2::Error - Can't connect to
MySQL server on 'test.dnsname.com' (61):\n  mysql2 (0.3.17)
lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'\n  activerecord (4.1.5)
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'\n  activerecord (4.1.5)
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'\n  activerecord (4.1.5)
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'\n  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'\n  activerecord (4.1.5)
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting directly to that database via mysql/terminal? I would try and rule out domain propagation and before getting looking into the problem on the Rails side.

Comment: Yes that works fine. It looks like something to do with terminal being open when I restarted the terminal and executed the application that seems to work as well. This could be the coincidence but that worked.